# How can I get the subnet of this IP?

Tags: python, networking

I have this IP: **192.168.1.1/24**, and I would like to get this **192.168.1.0/24**. Is there any built in method for this in python?

so basically, there are lots of ipadress belonging to  '192.0.2.0/28" as you can see below.

```
for addr in IPv4Network('192.0.2.0/28'):
    addr


IPv4Address('192.0.2.0')
IPv4Address('192.0.2.1')
IPv4Address('192.0.2.2')
IPv4Address('192.0.2.3')
IPv4Address('192.0.2.4')
IPv4Address('192.0.2.5')
IPv4Address('192.0.2.6')
IPv4Address('192.0.2.7')
IPv4Address('192.0.2.8')
IPv4Address('192.0.2.9')
```

now I solved this problem, but it doesnt looks nicely.

```
address = "192.168.0.3/28"
network = int(address.split("/")[-1])
new_string = address[:(len(address)-len(str(network))-1)]
last_ip = new_string.split(".")[-1]
first_part = new_string[:(len(new_string)-len(last_ip))]
print(first_part)
txt = str(first_part) + str(last_ip) + "/" + str(network)
print(txt)
print((last_ip))
isRun = True
while isRun:
    try:
        txt = str(first_part) + str(last_ip) + "/" + str(network)
        net4 = ipaddress.ip_network(txt)
        print(txt)
        isRun = False
        
    except:
        last_ip = int(last_ip) 
        last_ip -= 1
```

Comment: You can't solve it with string modification. There's math involved.

Comment: Have you tried the [built-in tools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ipaddress.html)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to create an [IPv4Interface](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ipaddress.html#ipaddress.IPv4Interface.network) then get the get the `network` attribute. Alterantively, if you know the subnet you want to check against you could use [subnet_of](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ipaddress.html#ipaddress.IPv4Network.subnet_of) to check if the network you specify is in the subnet of the other.

```
from ipaddress import IPv4Interface, ip_network

interface_a = IPv4Interface('192.0.2.1/24')
interface_b = IPv4Interface('192.0.2.7/28')
print(interface_a.network)
print(interface_b.network)

a = ip_network('192.0.1.1/24')
b =ip_network('192.0.2.8')

print(b.subnet_of(a))

# outputs
192.168.1.0/24
192.0.2.0/28
True
```